# Replace highlighting characters with something else

Tags: linux, terminal, regex, colors

I wish to replace color codes with something else. For example, running `cal` command i want to get some html tags instead of color codes:

```
     July 2015        
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
          1  2  3  4  
 5  <strong>6</strong>  7  8  9 10 11  
12 13 14 15 16 17 18  
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Executing `echo -e "\e[0;36m\e[41m some text"` will give you blue on red background.  Following the same example, I can find out the hex code of this color:

`echo -e "\e[0;36m\e[41m" | hexdump`

whitch is **5b1b 3b30 3633 1b6d 345b 6d31 000a**.
How do I write a `sed` command to replace all color codes to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: You're trying this via a pipe.
*NOTE: `cal` prints color codes only to a `tty`.*

First if you're going to replace what `cal` does send via the pipe, then  you need to check what `cal` sends into that pipe.

```
$ cal | od -t x1z -w$((($COLUMNS-12)/4))
0000000 20 20 20 20 20 4a 75 6c 69 20 32 30 31 35 20 20 20 20  >     Juli 2015    <
0000022 20 20 20 20 0a 73 c3 b6 20 6d c3 a5 20 74 69 20 6f 6e  >    .s.. m.. ti on<
0000044 20 74 6f 20 66 72 20 6c c3 b6 20 20 0a 20 20 20 20 20  > to fr l..  .     <
0000066 20 20 20 20 20 31 20 20 32 20 20 33 20 20 34 20 20 0a  >     1  2  3  4  .<
0000110 20 35 20 5f 08 20 5f 08 36 20 20 37 20 20 38 20 20 39  > 5 _. _.6  7  8  9<
0000132 20 31 30 20 31 31 20 20 0a 31 32 20 31 33 20 31 34 20  > 10 11  .12 13 14 <
0000154 31 35 20 31 36 20 31 37 20 31 38 20 20 0a 31 39 20 32  >15 16 17 18  .19 2<
0000176 30 20 32 31 20 32 32 20 32 33 20 32 34 20 32 35 20 20  >0 21 22 23 24 25  <
0000220 0a 32 36 20 32 37 20 32 38 20 32 39 20 33 30 20 33 31  >.26 27 28 29 30 31<
0000242 20 20 20 20 20 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  >     .            <
0000264 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 0a                       >          .<
0000277
```

Checking the hex-codes *(from `od -t x1`)* above you see the sequence
 `35 20 5f 08 20 5f 08 36 20 20 37`
where `35` (first two charcters) are the same as `5` and the last `37` is the same as `7` in the actual ouput (and in the ascii dump on the right).
Just before `37` you have a couple of `20` (spaces) and there is a `36` which is from the `6`.
Now just left of the `36` you see what you need to replace: `5f 08 20 5f 08`

```
$ cal | sed -re 's/\x5f\x08\x20\x5f\x086/<strong>6<\/strong>/'
     Juli 2015        
sö må ti on to fr lö  
          1  2  3  4  
 5 <strong>6</strong>  7  8  9 10 11  
12 13 14 15 16 17 18  
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

There you go.
I'll leave the task of making this general to you.

---

*An additional tip, check `man 5 terminfo` for things to try with `tput` - this will adapt as much as possible to the terminal type at hand at runtime.*

*So `tput setb 6` will set background color 6, if the terminal is capable of it. And likewise `tput sgr0` will reset all of the color settings to "normal".*

*And if you pipe tput output into e.g `od -t x1z` you will see what the output is.*

*End result: a much more portable script than one using `echo -e ...`*

Comment: Improved it to replace groups ` sed -re 's/\x5f\x08\x20\x5f\x086([0-9]*)/<strong>\0<\/strong>/'` , but it now would replace only one background and color variation, to match any color+background I need to learn the structure of this code. Thank you for a great answer, you da real mvp

Comment: Note: `\x08` is backspace, the following `6` is the '6' you have above. I suggest `\x08([0-9]{1,2})` for starters; that is - one or two digits.